# stack smashing detected while exiting thread

Tags: c, multithreading

I have some problem with my connection handler thread, the thread seem to work good but I receive this exception until it terminate:

```
*** stack smashing detected ***: ./listener2 terminated
Aborted (core dumped)
```

This is my thread:

```
void* SocketHandler(void* par) {
    struct thread_par* parameters=(struct thread_par*) par;
    int *csock = parameters->client_desc;
    MYSQL_RES *mysql_res;

    int buffer_len = 128;
    char client_message[buffer_len];
    int bytecount;
    memset(client_message, 0, buffer_len);
    if ((bytecount = read(*csock, client_message, buffer_len) == -1)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error receiving data\n");
        close(*csock);
        return 0;
    }
    printf("Received bytes %d\nReceived string \"%s\"\n", bytecount, client_message);
    char *sensor_alive = strtok(client_message, "&&");
    /*
     * the next operations will be done only for alive sensors
     */
    if (sensor_alive != NULL && strcmp(sensor_alive, "ALIVE") == 0) {
            puts("sensor Alive OK");
            //mysql_quwry returns
            //Zero for success. Nonzero if an error occurred.
            if (mysql_query(parameters->mysql_conn,
                    "--query--")) {
                fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(parameters->mysql_conn));
                mysql_free_result(mysql_res);
                return 0;
            }
            mysql_res = mysql_use_result(parameters->mysql_conn);
        }

    puts("Query executed");
    if (mysql_res->lengths > 0) {
        //we will do a second query , don't need anymore this
        mysql_free_result(mysql_res);

        /*
         * creation of a string containing the current time with the following format
         * YYYY-MM-dd hh-mm-ss
         */
        time_t t;
        struct tm* tm;
        char Date[11], Time[9];

        time(&t);
        tm = localtime(&t);

        char time_string[20];
        strftime(time_string, sizeof time_string, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tm);
        puts(time_string);

        /*
         * creation of the query
         * UPDATE sensors SET alive = 1, updated_at='YYYY-MM-dd hh-mm-ss' WHERE id_device='id';
         */
        char* query_part_1 = "--query--";
        char* query_part_2 = "--query--";
        char query[sizeof(query_part_1) + sizeof(query_part_2)+ sizeof(time_string)];
        strcpy(query, query_part_1);
        strcpy(query + strlen(query_part_1), time_string);
        strcpy(query + strlen(query_part_1) + strlen(time_string),
                query_part_2);

        //ALIVE UPDATE QUERY
        if (mysql_query(parameters->mysql_conn, query)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(parameters->mysql_conn));
            mysql_free_result(mysql_res);
            return 0;
        }
        //mysql_free_result(mysql_res);
        puts("Alive value updated");

        //jump the part 1 of the message
        strtok(NULL, "&&");
        //jump the part 2 of the message
        strtok(NULL, "&&");
        //jump the part 3 of the message
        strtok(NULL, "&&");
        //jump the part 4 of the message
        strtok(NULL, "&&");

        char* query_begin = "--query--";
        char* status_vector = strtok(NULL, "&&"); //part 5
        strtok(NULL, "&&"); //part 6 don't needed
        char* local_time = strtok(NULL, "&&"); //part 7
        char* timer = strtok(NULL, "&&"); //part 8
        char* created_at = strtok(NULL, "&&"); //part 9

        int total_len = 150;

        char query2[total_len];
        snprintf(query2, sizeof(query2), "%s('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s');",
                query_begin, status_vector, local_time, timer, created_at,
                time_string);

        puts(query2);

        if (mysql_query(parameters->mysql_conn, query2)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(parameters->mysql_conn));
            return 0;
        }
        //mysql_free_result(mysql_res);
        puts("Value updated");

    }


    /*
     * ending thread operations
     */
    //close(*csock);
    //free(csock);
    puts("exiting thread");
    //pthread_exit(0);
    return 0;
}
```

this is my output

```
Received bytes 0
Received string "ALIVE&&000000000035&&STATION NUM. 1&&40.1234234&&14.1234234&&0000000&&192.___&&00&&18:9:49&&2&&"
sensor Alive OK
Query executed
2014-10-16 18:08:10
Alive value updated
INSERT INTO -------;
Value updated
exiting thread
*** stack smashing detected ***: ./listener2 terminated
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I am not so good in C so I don't know how to solve my problem
can you help me?

Comment: Run your app under `valgrind`, it often detects this kind of errors.

Comment: It looks like you are not showing us your actual code or your actual output - you say the `puts(query2);` line prints `INSERT INTO -------;` but the according to the code it would be `--query--('..','..','..','..','..');`. Without accurate information, we can't help you.

Comment: Also, the `Received bytes 0` message vs. the non-empty string is not a good sign.

Comment: Another thing, for sensors that aren't alive you will try to dereference (and call `mysql_free_result` on) an uninitialized `mysql_res` pointer.

Comment: An unrelated issue: your comments/messages indicate that this function is running in a thread. Your use of `localtime` will lead to bogus records in your database (`localtime` uses one shared buffer for all callers). See `localtime_r` instead.

Comment: If 'buffer_len' chars are rx, the 'client_message' buffer will be full with no null-terminator and the printf call will overrun.  Plus all the other stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `query` variable is too small:

```
char query[sizeof(query_part_1) + sizeof(query_part_2) + sizeof(time_string)];
```

You have declared it to be large enough to hold only the number of characters in `query_part_1`, `query_part_2`, and `time_string`. You forgot to account for the string-terminating NUL byte, so the third `strcpy` call will write past the end of `query` and corrupt the stack.

Comment: It seems like very time there is a C network question, null-termination comes up as an issue:(

Answer (score 0):

You've got a buffer overrun, that's why you get "stack smashing detected" message. Check your code.
But I looked through your code and was unable to find any overrun, honestly :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `-fno-stack-protector`  as an option while compiling. This will result in getting a different error, mostly segmentation fault. As other answer mentioned this is clearly a buffer overrun. You can run your program with strace or gdb to detect where exactly is the problem in your code. e.g `strace ./a.out` or `gdb a.out`